# How to install RabbitMQ server on Ubuntu 16..04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rabbitmq

I need to install RabbitMQ server on Ubuntu, How can I achieve this? Is there any step by step guide to install RabbitMQ on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying official Docs, blogs and lots of other websites I have finally find the best **Step by step guide** for installing RabbitMQ server on ubuntu. I am attaching the link here:  https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-16-04-47